# How to allow public url access to Ubuntu Server installed in windows 10 as subsystem and using Ngnix with a Python Django & VueJS app

Tags: python, node.js, django, vue.js, nginx

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 22.04.6 on Windows 10 as a subsystem. I have an app which runs with Python, Django, VueJS, Postgres using Nodejs. I am using Ngnix Web Server and am able to get the "Welcome to Nginx!" message.

I have managed to get the app running on local ip http://127.0.0.1:8000.

I am stuck at getting the app running using the public ip for remote access. I don't have a domain name. I am hoping to use my Windows 10 PC as a web server till the time the app gets completely tested and functional.

I have followed steps as shown in:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04

The connection code is as below:

***/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:***

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

***/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:***

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bitrun
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/bitrun/SAFE_ERP
ExecStart=/home/bitrun/SAFE_ERP/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          SAFE_ERP.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

***/etc/nginx/sites-available/SAFE_ERP:***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 103.122.201.91;

    location = /static/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/bitrun/SAFE_ERP;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

***ufw status:***

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

***Port forwarding:***

```
ID  Service Port    Internal Port   IP Address  Protocol
1   80      80      192.168.0.99    All         Enabled
2   8080    8080    192.168.0.99    All         Enabled
3   443     443     192.168.0.99    All         Enabled
4   5432    5432    192.168.0.99    All         Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me go through:

Add host address to settings.py in Django.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '103.122.xxx.91']
```

In Ubuntu the below command helped me find the open ports:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

You may have to install net-tools:
`sudo apt install net-tools`

You will need the Ubuntu IP to proceed:
`hostname -I`

In my case it showed:
`172.21.14.174`

Use NETSH to add a port proxy that listens on your host port:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-linux-networking-apps-from-windows-localhost

In Windows open <cmd.exe> as an Administrator.
Then to view the currently connected ports use the NETSH command in DOS:

`netsh interface portproxy show all`

Add the port proxy using NETSH command:

(The connectaddress has to be your Ubuntu IP)

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80 connectaddress=172.21.14.174`

Once again to view the port proxy's:

`netsh interface portproxy show all`

You should see something like this:

```
Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:
Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
0.0.0.0         80          172.21.14.174   80
```

In my case, I have also forwarded 8000 for local LAN.

Remember that there is a co-relation with the listen port in nginx settings.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    server_name 103.122.xxx.91 safe-xxx.com;
    #...
    #...
}
```

You also need to forward port 80 in your Internet Router:

Finally, type your public ip address from anywhere and you should be able to connect:

```
http://103.122.xxx.91/
```